# Text box CSS not working in IE

Tags: html, css

In my website, for all text boxes I have applied CSS below:

```
input[type="text"],input[type="password"]
{
    width: 240px;
    background: transparent url('bg.jpg') no-repeat;
    color : #747862;
    height:30px;
    border:0;
    padding:4px 8px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

It's working fine in Mozilla but not in IE.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute selectors do not work up until around IE7. Use classes.

Comment: Post a link to a webpage or full source and I'll take another look

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from your attribute selectors.

```
input[type="text"],input[type="password"]
```

to

```
input[type=text],input[type=password]
```

Comment: make your css as general as possible (temporarily) until you get the most basic things working. make ALL inputs (not just text & password types) 400px tall and lime or something, and see if that works. If it does, you know that at least your css file is working and your text box is responding to that css. If it doesn't, get more basic. Rinse and repeat until you have an idea of what isn't agreeing with IE!

Comment: Tried, it's not reflecting in IE for any change. But in Mozilla still ok

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @meder, use class instead of Attribute selector, here is **[`Wokring sample`](http://jsfiddle.net/wBX78/)**

Comment: It's for whole site. I have to do changes on every textbox. Is there any other way to add CSS class to all text boxes of my site

Comment: Here all means input type text and password right? In that case use javascript to add CSS class to all your input. e.g. in jquery, $("input[type='text']").addClass("abc");

Answer (score 0):

the object should be selected using '' not by "" because if  you already start attribute value from anything else that 's not good

ex:

```
`"input[type="text"]"`     that's invalid
`"input[type='text']"`     that's valid**
```

if you do the operating using jquery that will be work in IE in all major browser.